# Should I avoid using aggregate roots?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

**PROBLEM**

There are four entities:

```
class Product : Entity<Product> {
    public virtual String Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
}

class Category : Entity<Category> { /* properties */ }
class Vendor : Entity<Vendor> { /* properties */ }
```

Neither of these four are defined as **components** and I don't know which one should I use (mark it with `IAggregateRoot` interface) as an aggregate root.

I need to easily access lists of *vendors*, *categories* to show them on a page while creating a new product.

Then it appears there should be three `Repository` instances as per these entities.

**ASIDE**

I've seen several largescale projects. They massively use lists of independent entities like Vendor, State, TechnicalOptions. I think it is logical to design things with aggregate roots but I don't know whether DDD principles are suitable there.

Comment: Why do you need to use a marker interface?  What benefit do you get by marking something as an `IAggregateRoot`?

Comment: That's just a convention nothing more. By using signature like `IRepository<T> where T : IAggregateRoot` you can constrain your repositories so only aggregate roots will be accessible from them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They look like different aggregates and it can be confirmed by applying the rule of **cascading delete**:

*The rule of Cascading Delete is sometimes cited as a good way to tell if you have a group of Entities or VOs that should be an Aggregate – if the parent was deleted all other parts of that Aggregate below would be deleted too.
So if it doesn’t make sense that a parent being deleted would also delete all children, then you don’t have an Aggregate, you just have a good old fashioned reference.*

In your case, given a Product if this get deleted you don't want cascading delete all the related categories as they may be related to other Products(you can apply this rules to the other Entities). So you will probably have one repository for each of them

Comment: I agree with this - it's often (simpler) said that entity belongs to aggregate if there is no reason for entity to exist when aggregate root is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have one AR reference an *instance* of another.  Rather reference by ID or use a Value Object.

Then try not to query your domain model as this leads to some lazy-lading and other nasty designs.  Rather create a thin query layer to return the data you need.  You may even want to denormalize some of the data for the query layer to improve performance.

Comment: ... and you are really using NHibernate or something similar?

Comment: @Stefan: typically I steer clear of ORMs.  I do perform my own mapping but having instances of an AR in another often leads to fancy footwork w.r.t. "fetching strategies" :)